# Setting up multiple sites on single virtual host

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, sites

So have an ubuntu server with lamp installed. We installed webmin so we would have a gui and we created a virtual host on it. There are three sites we want to host on this host and they are set up as so

```
myserver.com/site1
myserver.com/site2
myserver.com/site3
```

On site1 I want to use django which I set up sucessfully with mod_wsgi. But the problem is when I go to any page on the site like site2 or site3 I can see the django splash page on them. I only want django to be effecting the site1 directory not /site2 or /site3. I don't want to use django in site2 or 3.

Is this a problem caused by the way I set up the directives for the virtual host. Which is

```
<Directory /var/www/site1 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess site1 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup site1

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site1/apache/django.wsgi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WSGIScriptAlias` determines what Django serves. You've set it up to serve `/`, the root, so all paths are served by Django. If you only want it to serve `/site1`, use that:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /var/www/site1/apache/django.wsgi
```

Comment: It worked. Thank a million have been at this server for ages and its finally setup :D

Comment: I tried same trick but i am getting page not found error instead of the base page. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

your WSGIScriptAlias (which acts like apache Alias) is mapping '/' site-root (everything) to the django.wsgi script; try WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /var/www/site1/apache/django.wsgi instead